# Java Rest Client using self-signed Certificate

Tags: java, rest, ssl, certificate, client

Hello I'm trying to write a little Rest client which accesses our Cloud server (Rest Webservices). The connection is secured with a SSL Client Certificate which if I understand correctly is not signedby any Certification Authority, and am having problems.

I know that the certificate works fine as I can use this in other programming languages (e.g. C#, PHP, etc), and also because I am testing the API using Postman, however I cannot really understand how to do this in Java.

I have tried using the P12 certificate file, and I also have .key and .crt files, but still nothing changed. The .JKS file I have created using keytool.exe, and I presume it is correct (as far as I could understand).

This is the code I am using :

```
String keyPassphrase = certPwd;

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\Test\\Certificate\\idscertificate.jks"), keyPassphrase.toCharArray());

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, certPwd.toCharArray())
                .build();

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSslcontext(sslContext).build();

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(
                "https://url_that_I_am_using_to_call_my_rest_web_service"));
```

but every time I launch this I get an error:

***"unable to find valid certification path to requested target".***

As far as I could see this is because I don't have a Certification Authority to specify, am I correct?
Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you all for your help

Tommaso

/*******************
This is how I imported the P12 into the Keystore. I tried different ways, the last one i tried was:

First created the JKS:
***keytool -genkey -alias myName -keystore c:\Test\Certificate\mykeystoreName.jks***

then "cleaned up with:
***keytool -delete -alias myName -keystore c:\Test\Certificate\myKeystoreName.jks***

then imported the P12 file with:
***keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore c:\Test\Certificate\idscertificate.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore c:\Test\Certificate\myKeystoreName.jks -deststoretype JKS***

Result obtained:
***Entry for alias idsclientcertificate successfully imported.
Import command completed:  1 entries successfully imported, 0 entries failed or cancelled***

and if I check the content of the keystore I find my imported certificate. 
Nevertheless I still get the same error.

Thank you for your help.

/****************************Update February 8th *******************

Ok I tried everything, but really everything and now slowly giving up... the situation is the following:

using the following code so far:

```
SSLContextBuilder sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder();
            sslContext.loadKeyMaterial(readKeyStore(), userPwd.toCharArray());
            //sslContext.loadTrustMaterial(readKeyStore(), new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());

            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            sslContext.build());

            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
                    .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
                    .build();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://myhost.com/myrest/status");
            httpGet.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;charset=UTF8");
            httpGet.addHeader("Cookie", "sessionids=INeedThis");
            String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((userName+":"+userPwd).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);
            httpGet.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
```

Unfortunately still not working. I tried the following: - include my certificate in the default java cacerts, - specify the alias as my host name, - create a new jks, - load the p12 file, still nothing, same error.
Error Message I get is:

***javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target***

If I don't use a certificate, I get another error indicating that the certificate is missing therefore the certificate is loaded (also I see it in my IDE).

If I use the exact same certificate file from another platform (c# or using a browser) I get the correct response and object (therefore the certificate/password are valid)

**Is there any way that I can stop the validation of the certification path?**

Comment: How you created your jks file, could you describe the commands used?

Comment: Your client's *truststore* doesn't trust the *server's* certficate.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what does this exactly means? How come the same certificates work if I include them in a C# code or in PHP or in phyton but not from Java? Thank you

Comment: Java is somewhat more verbose to configure certificates, try this example here and implement it according http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java

Comment: @KennedyOliveira This isn't really Java's fault, it is the Apache HttpClient's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all thank you all for your help. I finally got it to work following these steps:
1 - I determined my root CA Cert using command:

> openssl s_client -showcerts -connect my.root.url.com:443

then I imported this certificate using Portecle.exe **(https://sourceforge.net/projects/portecle/)** but you can also import it using the normal keytool command, into my default Java Keystore (jre/lib/security/cacerts) 
**--> Make sure you assign the root URL as Alias (e.g. *.google.com if you would connect to a google API). This seems to be very important.**

Then I used the following code:
**First created the ServerSocketFactory:**

```
private static SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory() 
{
    try 
    {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        // Create a key manager factory for our personal PKCS12 key file
        KeyManagerFactory keyMgrFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        char[] keyStorePassword = pk12Password.toCharArray(); // --> This is the Password for my P12 Client Certificate
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(pk12filePath), keyStorePassword); // --> This is the path to my P12 Client Certificate
        keyMgrFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword);

        // Create a trust manager factory for the trust store that contains certificate chains we need to trust
        // our remote server (I have used the default jre/lib/security/cacerts path and password)
        TrustManagerFactory trustStrFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        char[] trustStorePassword = jksTrustStorePassword.toCharArray(); // --> This is the Default password for the Java KEystore ("changeit")           
        trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(trustStorePath), trustStorePassword);
        trustStrFactory.init(trustStore);

        // Make our current SSL context use our customized factories
        context.init(keyMgrFactory.getKeyManagers(), 
                trustStrFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

        return context.getSocketFactory();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.err.println("Failed to create a server socket factory...");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Then I created the connection using:**

```
public static void launchApi() 
{
    try 
    {
        //  Uncomment this if your server cert is not signed by a trusted CA              
        HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() 
        {
            public boolean verify(String urlHostname, SSLSession session)
            {
                return true;
            }};

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);


        URL url = new URL("https://myRootUrl.com/to/launch/api");

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((userName+":"+userPwd).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));  //Acc User Credentials if needed to log in
        urlConn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);
        urlConn.setRequestMethod("GET"); // Specify all needed Request Properties:
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json;charset=UTF8");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        urlConn.connect();

        /* Dump what we have found */
        BufferedReader in = 
            new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine = null;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is what worked for me. Thank you all, and also thanks to:
[this article that guided me on the right direction](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24022937/Sample-Java-code-that-does-an-HTTPS-Get-using-a-p12-cert.html)

Ciao

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `loadKeyMaterial` use `loadTrustMaterial`, the first one is for creating a `SSLContext` for a server, and the second one is for a client.

Example:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                               .loadTrustMaterial(keyStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                               .build();
```

Comment: Almost. `loadKeyMaterial ()` is for loading your own private key and certificate: `loadTrustMaterial()` is for loading an imported certificate belonging to the peer.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the proposed solutions workd. Any other idea?? I really cannot believe it is so hard to user unsigned certificates in Java!

Comment: @MrBreaker_1972 it’s a little hard but shouldn’t be that hard, try so instead of creating your Jks store and importing the other certificate, using it directly, and in the type out p12, java can read p12 files natively , you don’t need to create a jks store

Comment: Hello sorry guys, it was late night and I just posted without thinking.  I have moved my answer to the question. 
@EJP I tried also using 
loadTrustedMaterial(keystore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
(you can see that is in the code but it is commented as I was trying something different at this point) but I get exactly the same result and the same error.